# How to add geometries to an empty geometry layer in GEE

Tags: geometry, draw, layer, google-earth-engine

I would like to create two empty geometry layers and then add to them user-drawn geometries based on whether they are points or polygons.

```
// Initialize empty geomtry layers
var Layer1=
    ui.Map.GeometryLayer({geometries: null, name: 'points', color: '#ff0000'});
var Layer2=
    ui.Map.GeometryLayer({geometries: null, name: 'polygons', color: '#3b8b00'});
```